# Definition of rigid monoidal category generated by a category

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

> A rigid monoidal category is a monoidal category where every object has both left and right duals.

Is there a precise definition of rigid monoidal category generated by a category $C$? What would it mean for such category to be freely generated by $C$? Any reference?

Comment: Welcome to the magic world of monoidal categories, where "this result seems to be known as folklore inside some communities"! I still have to decide if it is true or false, but usually building the free thing over $C$ with property $P$ leads to somewhat unwieldy constructions.

Fortunately, it *seems* that in this particular case, the absence of an explicit argument was cured by [this recent paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.3827v4.pdf) (Appendix A, Definition 7).

Comment: Thank you. I guess what I am looking for has nothing to do with [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_category) of free category, correct? It seems that, by definition, the free category is generated only by a quiver, and not by a general category.

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of adjunction? What you're describing here (in both cases) is an instance of an adjunction, between the category of such-and-such structures, and the category of such-and-more-such structures: an overarching theme in category theory is the possibility to endow poor structure with richer features (any set has an associated free group; any graph an associated free category, and any category has an associated free rigid category).

Comment: In the opening post, you're asking about the existence of a free construction from monoidal categories, to *rigid* monoidal categories, imposing rigidity as an additional property on top of monoidality. On wikipedia, a graph is equipped with a category structure (much like a set is equipped with a free monoid structure taking the set of its finite lists, or a vector space taking its tensor algebra). These are instances of the same phenomenon:

Comment: ... given two categories $R$ (="rich") and $P$ (="poor") there is a functor $U : R \to P$ that forgets the properties that make a rich structure rich (e.g. being a group), yielding its $U$nderlying poor structure (the set of its element). Often there is a functor in the opposite direction, freely adding structure to a set, i.e building the free group/monoid/vector space/whatever; the second functor is a "left adjoint" to $U$.

Comment: Interesting. I am going to fully and freely speculate in the following: would it make sense to look for a natural transformation (which maybe here does not exist, I have no idea) between the two left adjoints of my case, to find a proper definition of free rigid monoidal category?

Comment: No, for evident reasons: nat tns exist between parallel functors; instead, here the free category functor is ${\sf Graph} \to {\sf Cat}$, whereas the free *rigid* category functor goes from ${\sf Cat}$ to ${\sf Rigid}$ (the "category of rigid categories", whatever that is). So, it makes no sense to build a nat tns between the two. For the sake of completeness, if $F$ is left adjoint to $U$ (notation: $F\dashv U$, pron.: *eff dash-vee you*) and $F'\dashv U'$, then nat tns $U \Rightarrow U'$ are exactly nat tns $F' \Rightarrow F$ (note the swapping of co/domains!).

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, that's right. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome. But please, consider my advice to undergo a more thorough and organised study of category-theoretic language *before* venturing elsewhere. The fact that category theory is a foundational dialect of mathematics doesn't mean that it can be fruitfully learned just *ex post*; it's [an old story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mithridatism): the best way to become immune to a poison is to ingest small, non lethal amounts of it periodically.

Comment: I am not learning exclusively ex post, I have enough years of study experience on my back to know this is not the right way. However, I do believe in the power of socratic dialogue, especially when it is stimulating me to learn things systematically. Thank you for the advice though.

Comment: Well, don't take my comment as just an unsolicited advice on how to study mathematics; I just have some years of experience as a student, and some years as a teacher, to suspect (without presumption of being right) when someone is lacking some prerequisites to digest a bigger topic. Thus my advice: you seem to lack some notions, this is making your life harder: what is the point of it? Finally, adjoint functors are -thank god!- easier that debating the nature of truth and beauty (but probably, CT is part of the answer to the socratic question: "what is Good? how to find it?").